# catalogProductUpdate multiple category IDs

Tags: php, magento

I'm trying to update the website and category IDs for a number of products in Magento and I'm having issues.  Here's my code:

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://magentohost/api/v2_soap/?wsdl');
$session = $client->login('apiUser', 'apiKey');
$productarray = array("12345" => "1,2,3", "67890" => "1,5,6");

foreach ($productarray as $product_id => $cats) {
    $update = array(
                'websites' => array(1,2,3), 
                'categories' => array($cats)
            );
    $updatewebsite = $client->catalogProductUpdate($session,$product_id,$update);
}
```

When I run this code, it's changing the products to have the new website IDs but it's only updating the category IDs with the first one in $cats.

For example, "12345" will only have category ID 1 and not 2 or 3 as it should have.

When I print out what $cats is for each product, it's showing me the info correctly (as "1,2,3" and "1,5,6" for the examples above).

I'm not sure what I've done but I just can't seem to get it to update all the category IDs.  I've got thousands of products to run through that all have different category IDs so I can't be doing this manually!

**EDIT - SOLVED**

I've changed my code so it's now like this (which works):

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://magentohost/api/v2_soap/?wsdl');
$session = $client->login('apiUser', 'apiKey');
$productarray = array("12345" => "1,2,3", "67890" => "1,5,6");

foreach ($productarray as $product_id => $cats) {
    $cats = explode(",", $cats);
    $update = array(
                'websites' => array(1,2,3), 
                'categories' => $cats
            );
    $updatewebsite = $client->catalogProductUpdate($session,$product_id,$update);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried passing `array(1, 2, 3)` instead of `"1,2,3"` (string)

Comment: I've just tried replacing `array($cats)` with `array(1,2,3)` and that's worked for the product - however, that's me doing a manual replace, which I can't do for all products.  Am I doing something wrong by having `$cats` in the array?  Is there anything I can do to change it so it works?

Comment: Use explode to split the comma delimited string into an array

Comment: I used explode on $cats and replaced `array($cats)` with `$cats` and that worked!  I've edited my question to show what I've done, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The categories property would expect an array of IDs, whereas you're passing a string. Try using `explode()` to break it up:

```
foreach ($productarray as $product_id => $cats) {
    $update = array(
        'websites' => array(1,2,3), 
        'categories' => explode(',', $cats)
    );
    $updatewebsite = $client->catalogProductUpdate($session,$product_id,$update);
}
```